# How should I use a GridBagLayout to have JComponents aligned like FlowLayout.Left

Tags: java, swing, alignment, gridbaglayout

I'm using the `GridBagLayout` , and I'd like to have my component layed out from left to the right like in a `FlowLayout` with `FlowLayout.LEFT`.
Following image explain what i have (on the left), and what I am aiming for. (on the right)

[image: MiMage]

Here is some code I wrote for that purpose. Commented line have been used while tring to (unsucesfully) figure out the solution:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Demo());     
    }
}

class Demo implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250,100));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("MyLabel1"); 
//      JLabel label1 = new JLabel("MyLabel1",SwingConstants.LEFT); 
//      label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
//      gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//      gbc.ipadx = 60;
//      gbc.ipady = 10;
        panel.add(label1,gbc);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("MyLabel2"); 
        panel.add(label2,gbc);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Never used before, but i m gonna check a video tutorial  to see if it could fit ours needs. Thank you

Comment: The MigLayout is overkill.  Just use a FlowLayout. Don't try forcing a square peg into a round hole. If you have multiple component in the grid bag layout, then create a child panel that uses a flow layout (left aligned) and add that panel to the panel using the grid bag layout. So given the context of the question just use the FlowLayout. It that doesn't help then post a proper question with the full requirement so we don't have to guess why you would do this.

Comment: I can't change the layout for design reasons. Neither i can add a panel to it.  I just have to position my component as required in my question.
Since it's the 3rd time i see you commenting my questions with useless ideas, i'd suggest you to avoid waste of time.

Comment: `I can't change the layout for design reasons`  but you just said you would look at the MigLayout. That is changing the layout so why would you bother reading up on that if you can't change the layout? `Neither i can add a panel to it` - again, why? A panel is a component that can contain multiply components. I don't see the difference. Like I say give us the full requirement. People can't provide a full answer with only half the information.

Comment: `You keep answering here and there, but i never received a piece of working code from you` - Based on your attitude in previous questions I am not going to spend the time to provide code when you don't appredciate the help. The forum is NOT about spoon feeding code. You  were given a link to the Swing tutorial in your last question (and ignored the suggestion). If you now read the tutorial it will explain how the constraints work for GridBagLayout. One of the constraints is forcing the layout to the center. you need to change that constraint.

Comment: Nice to know sometime you  say something relevant. 
I m on the tutorial, even if i have alread read it. It says:  **anchor:** _"Used when the component is smaller than its display area to determine where (within the area) to place the component"._ 
i tried by using GridBagConstraints.LINE_START and WEST too,  but nothing changed.
Any idea ?

Comment: Keep reading, you need to know how space is allocated when the frame is greater than the size of the components. The tutorial specifically mentions components will be clump together in the center if the constraint is not set. If you want to force your self to use a complex layout manager, then you need to take the time to understand the details. The GridBagLayout is one the most complex layout to use (constrainsts don't work indepently of one another), that is why nesting panels is often a simple solution as has already been suggested to you.

Comment: Thanks very much sir. I were missing the "weightx" evaluation.
It must be caused by that. 
I'm gonna make some tests and post the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93707/discussion-between-koop4-and-camickr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user **camickr** i found that:

**anchor** attribute of *GridBagConstraints*

*Used when the component is smaller than its display area to determine where (within the area) to place the component.*

and this is properly set to:

```
 gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

but it is not enough, since:

**weightx** and **weighty** attribute of *GridBagConstraints*

*Weights are used to determine how to distribute space among columns (weightx) and among rows (weighty); this is important for specifying resizing behavior.
Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the center of their container.*

give it a value between 0.1 and 1 before adding JComponent and it will works:

```
   gbc.weightx = 0.1; //0.1 works well in my case since frame can't be resized
```

Thanks everyone.